# Python 2.x --> Python 3.x upgrade

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, upgrade

I'm on Mac OS X El Capitan, which comes with Python 2.7.10; I want to upgrade to 3.x.

I've downloaded the 64-bit version from the website and installed it through `brew` however whenever I type `python --version` into the terminal the version is always 2.7.10. I can make terminal run in 3.x by typing `python3` but I need the system to run on `python3` as I'm running code through Sublime. I've been told not to change the systems python code as it can mess up other applications so am pretty stumped on how to do it.

Comment: The thing you need to fix, surely, is whatever is running code through Sublime. I'm sure there will be a setting in that app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/200/getting-started-with-django/3203/virtual-environment#t=201611111410298972616

Comment: The word "upgrade" is pretty controversal... Basically, half Python programmers uses Python2, and the other half of them uses Python3. The main reason for this is that porting a code from Python2 to Python3 can become really hard. But still, half of the world uses Python2, is not planning to switch for Python3, and would probably have very little to gain from doing so.

Comment: assuming that `python` is located at `/usr/bin/python`,  it is probably a symlink to python2.7 , You can change that to python3.x

Comment: @DanielRoseman so the code is written in sublime but run through terminal , which is still in 2.7. The thing I'm finding difficult is making terminal run Sublime python files in Python3.x

Comment: @lxer - a great solution if you want to break all python 2 based programs on your system. If you don't want to break them, python 3 is happy to live side-by-side with python 2.

Comment: So Sublime has nothing to do with this at all? In which case why can't you just run `python3 my_file.py`?

Comment: You probably want to look into multiple virtual environment support for different python project using sublime. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963030/sublime-text3-and-virtualenvs

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the  default intepreter in sublime. And add a 3 in the shebang line like this:

`#/usr/bin/evn python3`.

If you really want to know the python3 version you have to type:

`python3 --version`

As other people said python(2) and python3, are the same but different(but still the same...)