# Is it possible to get code editors in virtualenv?

Tags: python, terminal, virtualenv, code-editor

I recently downloaded virtualenv on my MacOSX Sierra (10.12.2). I'm not very experienced with virtualenv and I've been coding using the interactive interpreter in terminal and I was wondering if there was an alternate way that I could use an editor(IDLE, Sublime, etc.) and still use it in virtualenv. Would I just install an editor into virtualenv or am I limited to only the interactive shell?

Answer (score 0):

You are not limited to only interactive shell. For your coding part you can download and install sublime text and open your project (any project irrespective of the language you use) and get started. Here is a quick guide for getting started in sublime text : [sublime text getting started](https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/)

You might also want to take a look at this post: [SublimeREPL plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963030/sublime-text3-and-virtualenvs)

Comment: I think OP wants to use different virtual environments. Is that possible in sublime?

Comment: Well yes, its possible with SublimeREPL plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***[atom](https://atom.io/packages/virtualenv)*** editor, inside that you can use `virtualenv` plugin