# Using Tensorflow as environment of Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, importerror

I've installed anaconda (python3.6) and installed tensorflow as mentioned here:

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
```

and activated tensorflow, now I want to  run example codes in sublime text3 
and I can't import tensorflow. I've tried the same in Spyder  with the same result.

```
 import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong here? 
(the code is definitely correct)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are doing here is creating a virtual environment named tensorflow.

The correct way to do it is: (in the same order)

```
$ conda create --name yourenv python=3.5 anaconda
$ source activate yourenv
$ conda install -n yourenv tensorflow
```

Then, from the `ipython` terminal do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

---

To make things work in SublimeText editor, please follow the steps as documented here: [sublimeText and VirtualEnv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25002696/2956066)

Basically, you need to add the following line in the project settings.

```
"settings": {
    "python_interpreter": "/home/user/.virtualenvs/example/bin/python"
}
```

For people using Anaconda distribution, it's little bit different.

```
"settings": {
        "python_interpreter": "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python"
    }
```

Comment: I've managed to use is in spyder now but still having trouble running it in sublime text