# How to make the import PyQt5 working in sublime text?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have installed `PyQt5` and `PyQt5-tools` using command prompt and `pip install PyQt5` then pip install `PyQt5-tools` and `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5` everything installed fine I then put in the following code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys
 
def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)
    win.setWindowTtitle("Darts Scoreboard")
 
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
 
window()
```

but get the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bilal/Documents/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: No module named PyQt5
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/bilal/Documents/hello.py"]
```

I have checked all sort of youtube help advice and instructions and nothing seems to work can someone please please help

Comment: Have you used `sudo pip install PyQt5` or installed globally without a virtualenv?

Comment: I used this command and the result is that the `requirement already satisfied` and installed it globally but still it is not being imported in the sublime text. Although it is working fine when imported in terminal

Comment: I think the issue is that you have installed PyQt5 using sudo(available for sudo user) and your sublime text is running your python file with a non sudo user. Try running `sudo python <yourfile>`

Comment: It worked but the sublime text is still showing me the error. Although I run this `sudo python <myfile>` in the terminal and executed the sublime code but how can I remove this `module error` in the sublime text

Comment: i have composed an answer for your question, have a look

Answer (score 0):

The solution for such a scenario when non sudo user is unable to access package, would be to remove the package with sudo privilege and reinstalling it as non root user, like this

---

```
sudo pip uninstall PyQt5
```

and reinstalling it without sudo privileges

```
pip install PyQt5
```

I would highly suggest you to use virtualenv in python [check this out](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), which you can activate whenever needed.

for setting up virtual env for sublime [have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963030/sublime-text3-and-virtualenvs)