# How do I use Virtual Environments with SublimeREPL?

Tags: python, virtualenv, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimerepl

I am a beginner to coding in general and I just found out that we could create virtual environments and was soon disappointed to see that there was no tutorial or answer anywhere for a Windows user and the only one I found was **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963030/sublime-text3-and-virtualenvs#comment57264687_25002696)**. Which kinda solves my problem but isn't ideal. And I wanted to follow forms that actually **SOLVED** my problem but they were for mac and linux users. So can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mentioned in the [docs](https://sublimerepl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#python):

> For virtualenv created environments to be discoverable by SublimeREPL
> they should be created or symlinked in one of the following:

- ~/.virtualenvs default for virtualenvwrapper
- ~/.venvs default for venv

> Alternatively, more paths can be added to “python_virtualenv_paths” in
> the SublimeREPL configuration file.

If your virtualenvs are created in another directory add them to `SublimeREPL.sublime-settings`. For me, they are in `~/Envs`:

```
{
    "python_virtualenv_paths": ["C:\\Users\\my_username\\Envs"]
}
```

Assuming you're using the correct path, `sublimeREPL: Python - virtualenv` allows you to select the venv you want to work with:

Comment: thanks a lot, I have been able to load the virtual environment through the drop-down menu but when I run my file it shows an error that the selenium module doesn't exist but when I type it into the REPL it gives no error.

Comment: Probably you need [Virtualenv package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Virtualenv) additionally, to run scripts within a venv.