# Modify title of SublimeREPL in tab

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimerepl

I'm using the [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) package. The title in the tab where the code is running is very long and makes navigating the tabs a hassle:

[image]

Can the title shown in the REPL tab be modified and/or suppressed all together?

Comment: How do you configure and start the REPL?

Comment: Pretty much as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25002696/1391441

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25002696/1391441), one of the steps was to create a custom plugin to run your virtualenv REPL. You can customize the tab's title by changing the `repl_open` method to pass an `"external_id"` key and value. Here is the modified plugin code:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class ProjectVenvReplCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    Starts a SublimeREPL, attempting to use project's specified
    python interpreter.
    """

    def run(self, edit, open_file='$file', name='Python'):
        """Called on project_venv_repl command"""
        cmd_list = [self.get_project_interpreter(), '-i', '-u']

        if open_file:
            cmd_list.append(open_file)

        self.repl_open(cmd_list=cmd_list, name=name)

    def get_project_interpreter(self):
        """Return the project's specified python interpreter, if any"""
        settings = self.view.settings()
        return settings.get('python_interpreter', '/usr/bin/python')

    def repl_open(self, cmd_list, name):
        """Open a SublimeREPL using provided commands"""
        self.view.window().run_command(
            'repl_open', {
                'encoding': 'utf8',
                'type': 'subprocess',
                'cmd': cmd_list,
                'cwd': '$file_path',
                'syntax': 'Packages/Python/Python.sublime-syntax',
                'external_id': name
            }
        )
```

And here you can modify the arguments you send to the plugin to define the tab's name (the default being `Python`):

```json
{
    "keys": ["f6"],
    "command": "project_venv_repl",
    "args": {
        "open_file": null,
        "name": "My Project Name"  // insert name of choice here.
    }
},
```